# understanding carry for Fixed Income Securities in Pedersen

Tags: fixed-income, bond, futures

I'm following the famous paper [Carry](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/%7Elpederse/papers/Carry.pdf) of Pedersen et al. I have a particular question about the section Global Fixed Income Carry.

My main questions are around equation 15. They define Carry as

$$C_t:=\frac{S_t-F_t}{F_t} (1)$$

for a fully funded position. My first question, why is this equivalent to for fixed income securities?

$$\frac{P_{t+1}^{T-1}+D\cdot 1_{[t+1\in \text{coupon dates}]}-P_t^T}{P_t^T} (2)$$

Comment: How does he move from first to second line? Add and substract $P_{t+1}^{T-1}(y_t^T)$ and use the definition of yield (discussed before in the same section). Agree that some of their notation is a bit confusing.

Comment: @fesman could you please give some more details in an answer so that I can also accept it? thanks!

Comment: @swissy it is a previous version of the paper. So check also the new one. However, I would be also be very interested in seeing why these two definition for carry are the same

Comment: I think they only claim that they are approximately the same.

Comment: @fesman in a newer version the use $C_t=\frac{S_{t+1}^{T-1}-F^T_t}{F^T_t}=\frac{S^{T-1}_{t+1}-(1+r^f)S^T}{(1+r^f)S^T}$, looks like the $(1+r^f)$ is somehow too "much" on the equation

Comment: By newer version of the paper, do you mean this one from 2016 https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2298565 or another?

Comment: @noob2 yes exactly.

Comment: In the definition of carry, don't they assume $F_{t+1}=S_t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the definition:

$C_t:=\frac{S_t-F_t}{F_t}$

Per the article, it should actually be: (tomorrow minus today ) divided by today:

$C_t=\frac{F_{t+1}-F_t}{F_t}$

but they assume price does not change so $S_{t+1}=S_t$. An equivalent assumption for the bond would be that the YTM does not change. But there are two predictable (model free) characteristics of bonds: it pays coupon and its maturity shrinks as time progresses. So tomorrow (t+1) the same bond will have one fewer day to maturity, and if tomorrow happened to be a coupon date, then the bond holder will get coupon as well, so the equivalent of $F_ {t+1}$ is $P^{T-1}_{t+1}+D (\,\mathrm{if}\; t+1 \;\mathrm{is \,coupon \,date}\,)$

Re-comment, the price of the asset or exchange rate is a random process so it will vary over time, and then there is the arbitrage/parity type relationship between the current price and the forward/future price. In the calculation of their carry, they assumed that the price remains constant over time, but the parity relationships are deterministic so they hold. If you have a non-dividend paying stock, then $F_t=S_t (1+r)$. If you substitute into the carry equation:

$C_t:=\frac{S_t-F_t}{F_t}=\frac{S_t-S_t (1+r^f)}{F_t}=-r^f \frac{S_t}{F_t}$

So the carry is minus funding rate. And if you have a dividend paying stock or FX, then $F_t=S_t (1+r)-E[D]$,so carry will be dividend minus the funding rate:

$C_t:=\frac{S_t-F_t}{F_t}=\frac{S_t-S_t (1+r^f)+E[D]}{F_t}=\left(\frac{E[D]}{S_t}-r^f \right)\frac{S_t}{F_t}$

So essentially they assume the price is not random over time, but parity type relationships hold.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the questions is, why $F_t = S_t$. I do agree with your form of $F_{t+1}$. The problem is for $F_t$ we use $(1+r^f)S_T$. If $F_{t+1}=P^{T-1}_{t+1}+D(\text{if }t+1\text{ is coupon date})$, then $F_t =S_t$, which seems wrong

Comment: Is it clear what I mean :) otherwise let me know as I'm very thankful for your help

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, you mean $f_t=S_t(1+r^f)$? This would be the case for a stock that pays no dividends?

Comment: If you check the new version, link the comments above one can see that they write $F^\tau_t = (1+r^f_t)S_t^\tau$

Comment: thanks, let me add details based on the current version, and we can then correct me if i get it wrong based on what you have seen in the new version!

Comment: thanks for your patience....I fully agree with all of what you are saying. The point which is not so clear is the following. Look at equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ in the question. If both carry definition are the same, we see that $F_t=P_t^T$, in the new version $P_t^T$ is denoted by $S_t^\tau$. But on the other hand they wrie $F_t=(1+r^f)S^\tau_t$. Which are equal iff $r^f$ is zero. And this the part which confuses me....

Comment: Let's say you have the stock price over time: $S_{t}, S_{t+1},S_{t+2}$, one month forward (consent tenor): $F_{t}^1, F_{t+1}^1,F_{t+2}^1$, 2 months forward $F_{t}^2, F_{t+1}^2,F_{t+2}^2$.  If interest rate were to be constant (say!), $S_{t}= S_{t+1}=S_{t+2}$, $F_{t}^1=F_{t+1}^1=F_{t+2}^1$, and $F_{t}^2=F_{t+1}^2=F_{t+2}^2$. But at a given point, say t, $F_{t}^1=S_{t} \left( 1+\frac{r^f}{12}\right)$ and $F_{t}^2=S_{t} \left( 1+\frac{r^f}{12}\right)^2$. Does that make sense in light of the new version of the paper?

Comment: I'm very thankful for your patient. I think from my side we are almost there :) In your notation, why should constant interest rate imply $S_t = S_{t+1}$ etc? Second question, this still doesn't imply that $F_t = S_t$. I'm very sorry for my unawareness

Comment: The constant interest rate I used was just to facilitate the presentation of the relationship between spot and forward rates of different tenors. The $S_t=S_{t+1}$ is the assumption the authors make to facilitate their definition of carry. Today forward of 1 month tenor will settle to spot rate one month from now, so $F_{t+1M}^{1M}=S_{t+1M}$, thinking of $F_{t+1M}^{1M}$ as the price at time ${t+1M}$ of tenor fixed at time t, so remaining tenor will be zero at maturity. The key is the combination of subscript and superscript.